# Match start of a line or nothing using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following in a configuration file:

```
property = 10
#property = 10
#this is a test for #property
#this is a test for property
```

And I'm trying to come up with a regex to match only the first 2 cases:

```
property = 10 //this one
#property = 10 //and this one
#this is a test for #property
#this is a test for property
```

So far, what I did was:

```
#property.*|^property.*
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I tried other variants, but the results change for the worst:

```
^#property.*|^property.*
[^\s]#property.*|^property.*
```

Here's the link of the online regex that I'm using:

https://regex101.com/r/K2tm75/2

I will use this regex in a grep command as part of a bash script.

Comment: There was a recommendation asking if you tag regex, it will be better if you tag the language also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you match `#property` or `property` at the start of the string.

I suggest

```
^#?property.*
```

or - to only match them with `=` and digits at the end:

```
^#?property *= *[0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/KPrcHP/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/b2mCgl/1).

The `^#?property.*` matches the start of the input, then an optional `#` (`#?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences, then `property` and then any 0+ chars).

The second pattern - `^#?property *= *[0-9]+$` - matches a similar beginning, but, after `property`, matches zero or more spaces, `=`, zero  or more spaces and then 1+ digits and the end of string (with `$`).

Comment: `^#*property` would match `##property` as well (for better or worse..?).

Comment: @JamesBrown: The `*` quantifier matches zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern. I do not know if `####property text...` should be matched or not. If yes, then yes, `*` is a better quantifier to use here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answer just made me realize about /gm. Worked flawlessly with that switch.

Comment: @MaximilianoSantaCruz: Well, you do not seem to need those modifiers with Bash. Anyway, glad to help! :)